# How do you output a single INT of one set in a T-SQL Upsert rather than two?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL Upsert that I am trying to return an INT using the `OUTPUT` clause for either query depending on which executed. I noticed both the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` outputs two sets. One can be blank while the other has the data 'FilmNumber'. In c# I read the output data using `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the data but if the data does not exist in the `UPDATE` it will return null and ignore the second result set of the `INSERT` which has the data I need.

Using the `ExecuteScalar` reads the NULL/Empty result set from the `UPDATE` rather than reading the `INSERT` result set that has the data. How can I return the `OUTPUT` which is a single int from either query that affected the data using this same SQL call?

I know I can use the `IF ELSE` to return one set with the single int but is it possible with this?

```
UPDATE Film WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET Film = @FilmName
OUTPUT INSERTED.FilmNumber
WHERE FilmNumber = @FilmNumber
    
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Film (FilmName, FilmNumber)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.FilmNumber
    VALUES(@FilmName, (SELECT MAX(FilmNumber) FROM OtherTable) + 1)
END
```

Film table

| FilmName | FilmNumber |
| --- | --- |
| Angels & Demons | 3 |
| Cats | 2 |

**WANTED** results for an insert/update, one result set:

| FilmNumber |
| --- |
| 3 |

**CURRENT** results for an insert (It creates a result set for the update with updates nothing 0 rows affected so null/empty and then creates a result set for the insert 1 row affected but the `ExecuteScalar` reads the first set rather than reading the `FilmNumber`.

Update

| FilmNumber |
| --- |
| NULL |

Insert

| FilmNumber |
| --- |
| 3 |

I tried using a table with an INTO clause but that will change c# to use `ExecuteReader` to read the set and that may have the NULL inserted from the update if it does not exist yet.

Comment: please add your table with data and wanted result, maybe then we can help you

Comment: @nbk Updated thanks!

Comment: See you trying to do a MERGE? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: yes it returns two outputs because it first try to update and if that failsm (output NULL) it wout insert Aand return a number, but  i don't get ypur problem the output would be always @FilmNumber, so why bother

Comment: Are you trying to use these output tables as some kind of validation that your commands were successful?  Or are you trying to use these output tables to somehow determine if an existing row was found (and updated), or if a new row was inserted.  Perhaps let us know exactly what the end goal of your requirement is - because the actions you are performing seem a bit unusual and somewhat redundant (as @nbk pointed out - why just try and return a value from the database when you provided that value and already know what it is?)

Comment: @Craig Yes to your second question. I know the query is a bit unusual since that is what I was given. The '@FilmNumber' from the second query SELECTS from a table and returns its max FilmNumber from said table + 1 to get a new max number (wrapped in IFF for null check to start at 1) which I understand is also incorrect. I have edited the question to reflect this. I went with the IF / ELSE for now but may try the MERGE.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to output both into a table variable, then select from it.

```sql
DECLARE @temp TABLE (FilmNumber int PRIMARY KEY);

SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE Film WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    SET 
        Film = @FilmName
    OUTPUT INSERTED.FilmNumber
    INTO @temp (FilmNumber)
    WHERE 
        FilmNumber = @FilmNumber;
    
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Film (FilmName, FilmNumber)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.FilmNumber
        INTO @temp (FilmNumber)
        VALUES (@FilmName, @FilmNumber);
END;

COMMIT;

SELECT FilmNumber
FROM @temp;
```

Or you could use a `MERGE`, note that you still need locking hints.

```sql
MERGE Film AS f WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
  USING (VALUES
    (@FilmName, @FilmNumber)
  ) AS s(FilmName, FilmNumber)
  ON f.FilmNumber = s.FilmNumber
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
       Film = @FilmName
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (FilmName, FilmNumber)
      VALUES (@FilmName, @FilmNumber)
  OUTPUT inserted.FilmNumber
;
```

Having said all that, it's kinda weird to output the primary key when you know that already.